# How to change CSS class to ascendent

Tags: css, amp-html

I can't figure out how to do this, and don't know if it's even possible:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text"></div>
    <a href="javascript:;" class="view">View more</a>
<div>
```

How can I add a class to the div `.text` if I click on the link `.view` with only CSS?
I can't use javascript as I'm building a page with its css for AMP

Comment: You simply cannot accomplish that through CSS alone.

Comment: you need js to add a class to the element.

Comment: thanks guys for your lightning answers :) Actually i can't use javascript as I'm building a page for AMP :/

Comment: why do you have href="javascript:;"  then ?

Comment: i don't really understand your question! what would I have instead?

Comment: is href="javascript: ;" calling a js function or is it empty?

Comment: it's an empty link

Comment: and what if I place the link before .text div, will that be possible?

Comment: you can't add class to it. But you can select the sibling through css

Comment: sibling should be fine as I can set some rules for the elements :) so basically it would be great if i can do this: `a.clicked .text { ... }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146705/discussion-between-karthick-and-websphere).

Comment: found a better way you can use #id:target

Comment: how would you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can give a fragment to the anchor instead of 'javascript:;' then you can utilize the :target state of anchor.

```
#view-more {
  display: none;
}

#view-more:target {
  display: block;
}
  <div class="container">        
        <a href="#view-more" class="view">View more</a>
        <div class="text" id="view-more">text</div>
    <div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/karthick6891/g89fdagu/

But the best alternative is to use checkbox so you will have the :checked attribute, which is more robust

Comment: this solution is great too and works better for me as i don't need to set an empty link which is not AMP valid! i tried it and works like a charm. however, when i click on the link, it adds the anchor "#view-more" to the URL, is it possioble to prevent that from happening?

Comment: No you can't avoid it. Thats how the browser detects the target.

Comment: ah :/ and do you by any chance know how to set an empty link valid for AMP?

Comment: Sorry no idea. But why do you need an empty link. Cant you change your link to a button

Comment: sure, i can't change it into a button, i'll just need some extra css :D 
If you have to chose between :target and + .text solution, which one would you pick?

Comment: I will pick checkbox +.text , it has more control. lets say you want to close view more then :target wont work.

Comment: I see, and if i don't need to close view?

Comment: well, i'm realising now that if i use a button, i'll have to use the + .text or checkbox as i won't have a href="" :)

Comment: you can use :target. But its upto you.

Comment: thanks a lot @karthick and to all the amazing stackoverflow community for your time and help ;) cheers

Comment: @Pocketninja: yes and stackoverflow is good in helping everyone learn one or two things daily.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing close to it I could think of would be to use the sibling styling

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors

```
.text + a {
    border: 2px solid #fc0;
}
```

So it is the next sibling item that is style and if you could order your structure as follows:

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="view">View more</a>
    <div class="text">
</div>
```

Then maybe you could have

```
.text {
    display: none;
}
a:active + text {
    display: block;
}
```

You could then maybe use table row styling like the following to reorder them

setting the "a" as:
display: table-footer-group

setting the "text" as:
display: table-header-group

All without Javascript,  but obviously the minute you haven't got the link active the text box disappears :-D

Soooooooooo you could have a checkbox instead..? when it is active the Adjacent sibling can be styled:

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/

```
input[type=checkbox] + .text {
    display: none;
} 
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .text {
    display: block;
}
```

**Another possible solution**

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <label for="textView">Button Style Me</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="textView" class="view">
    <div class="text">Some Text</div>
</div>
```

STYLING

```
input[type=checkbox] + .text {
    display: none;
} 
input[type=checkbox]:checked + .text {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: do you by any chance know how to set an empty link? `href:"javascript:;"` doesn't validate in AMP :/

Comment: can you just remove the href and have <style>a { cursor: pointer; }</style>

Comment: But I think having a checkbox that hides itself when checked and reveals a container.  Or, you could have a label styled up to look like a button which points at the hidden checkbox which when checked activates the .text?  That might be a better solution.

Comment: I finally used a button and works just fine. I also tried the checkbox + label and worked also :) thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

CSS cannot do that, CSS is only styling. You can however do it with javascript.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="text"></div>
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="myFunction()" class="view">View more</a>
<div>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("text");
    for(var index = 0; index < elements.length; index++) {
        var element = elements[index];
        element.className += "otherclass";
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I unfortunately can't use JS as it's for an AMP page!! :/

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` will return a NodeList not a single element. That code will throw an error.